# Gap between <tr>

Tags: html, html-table

I am creating a table that has 2 rows, that has different colors. There appears to be a gap between the rows and I want to close the gap, how can I do that?

[image]

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="grey">
<table width="50%" style="margin:auto;">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="white" align="center">
<img src="">Test
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#99CB55">
<img width="50%" src="xxx">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to use the css `<style>` because I'm sending this via Email (PHPMailer) and all the text will only be in HTML (+CSS using )

Comment: try ` table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}`.

Comment: @Suchit border-spacing did the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `table {border-spacing: 0; }`

```css
table {border-spacing: 0; }`
```

```html
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="grey">
<table width="50%" style="margin:auto;">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="white" align="center">
<img src="">Test
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#99CB55">
<img width="50%" src="xxx">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```